# how to set value when field in Firestore database has different data type?

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore, getter-setter, getter

My firestore database has a field called "Unit".

Among many of my documents, I have Units of different data types.
Not sure if it is clear, so here is an eg

Class 1 has a field called unit and its data type is **String**.

Class 2 has a field called unit and its data type is **long**

How can I use the get method to call for unit value from java?

```
String unit;
unit = selectedClass.getUnit();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the field value can be of multiple types in the database, the field and the getter/setter in the Java code must be of a type that can handle all data types. Typically this means that it'll have to be an `Object`.

```
class yourClass {
  private Object unit;

  public Object getUnit() {
    return unit;
  }
  public void setUnit(Object unit) {
    this.unit = unit;
  }
}
```